# Why can't I browse the internet while Parity is running?

Tags: parity

I am using Parity/v1.5.0-unstable-a7037f8-20161126/x86_64-macos/rustc1.13.0 
After I start the node, every page request in the browser fails with a "Server not found" error. As soon as I turn the Parity node my internet connection works again as expected.

These are the differences between netstat with parity running and parity off. Maybe this can help to detect if this is a port collision?

```
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.30303        localhost.62536        ESTABLISHED
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.62536        localhost.30303        ESTABLISHED
< tcp4       0      0  davids-mbp.local.62315 128.199.55.137.30303   ESTABLISHED
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.http-alt     localhost.61962        ESTABLISHED
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.61962        localhost.http-alt     ESTABLISHED
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.8180         *.*                    LISTEN     
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.http-alt     *.*                    LISTEN     
< tcp4       0      0  localhost.8545         *.*                    LISTEN     
< tcp4       0      0  *.30303                *.*                    LISTEN
---
> tcp4       0      0  davids-mbp.local.63153 52.222.157.6.https     ESTABLISHED
> tcp4       0      0  davids-mbp.local.62942 fra16s18-in-f14..https ESTABLISHED
59,61d51
< udp6       0      0  *.62792                *.*                               
< udp4       0      0  *.62792                *.*                               
< udp4       0      0  *.30303                *.*                               
134,138c124,127
< 90d5bc5341b2c3b5 stream      0      0                0 90d5bc5341b2c60d                0                0 /Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/sock/cliapi.sock
< 90d5bc5341b2c60d stream      0      0                0 90d5bc5341b2c3b5                0                0
< 90d5bc533cd467fd stream      0      0                0 90d5bc5341b2cf6d                0                0 /var/run/mDNSResponder
< 90d5bc5341b2cf6d stream      0      0                0 90d5bc533cd467fd                0                0
< 90d5bc5341b2d0fd stream      0      0 90d5bc5349c5d01d                0                0                0 /Users/uscreen/.parity/jsonrpc.ipc
---
> 90d5bc533cd467fd stream      0      0                0 90d5bc5341b2c60d                0                0 /var/run/mDNSResponder
> 90d5bc5341b2c60d stream      0      0                0 90d5bc533cd467fd                0                0
> 90d5bc5341b2d0fd stream      0      0                0 90d5bc5341b2cf6d                0                0 /Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/sock/cliapi.sock
> 90d5bc5341b2cf6d stream      0      0                0 90d5bc5341b2d0fd                0                0
```

Comment: Could be a port clash, depending on how you've got your browsing set up? Try giving Parity a different port using `--dapps-port=<a_port_that_isn't_8080>` e.g. `--dapps-port=9090`.

Comment: I tried it like this `parity ui --dapps-port=9090`and like this `parity ui --dapps-port 9090`, but the port is not used. I still uses 8180. (I don't know why it is 8180 on my computer in all the tutorials it says that it should be 8080, maybe something else was running on 8080 when I first started parity).

Comment: The Trusted UI server runs on port `8180`, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: You could try changing the UI port using `--ui-port <port>` option. I'm not sure where the clash will be though. You could also try looking at the output of `netstat -a` with and without Parity running, and with and without your browser running. (Direct the outputs to a file, then run `diff`, if you're on Linux. Might be other stuff in there that changes though... )

Comment: I tried changing the ui-port, but browsing is blocked no matter if I use the --ui-port option or not. I made a diff of the netstat results. Unfortnately I cannot read anything in them. I add the to my question above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check if the problem persists when running `parity --mode=offline` as well?

Comment: Does this also happen with the latest beta version 1.6.3? Could you also try to reset your settings by completely moving (not removing!) your parity folder from `.local/share/` to somewhere else (and make sure you have backups of your keys), and start a clean instance without any parameters?

Comment: After updating to parity 1.6.4 the problem doesn't occur for me anymore. Thanks a lot!